# Changing Data source on list of reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, odbc

I have to open 300+ reports and change the data source to a new database while also changing the tables included to the new database. As you see the following image is unchanged:

[image: Crystal Reports Current Data Source]

I need to change all the tables to "testepicor" but I would like to not have to open each report and do them separately. Is there a way I can make something in C# to handle this work for me? I am fluent in C# but have never used it with crystal reports.

I would like all these tables to have "Catalog: TESTEPICOR"

[image: Crystal Reports Current Data Source]

like this one

[image: Crystal Reports Current Data Source]

Thank you for reading!

Current code (so this turned out to not be possible):

```cs
    public static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> AllReports = GetReports();
            ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
            foreach (string report in AllReports)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(@"\\cytepicortest\EpicorData\CustomReports\" + report);
                Console.ReadLine();
                cryRpt.Load(@"\\cytepicortest\EpicorData\CustomReports\" + report);


                SetDatabaseLogon(cryRpt, "odbcuser", "*", "testepicor");
            }
            cryRpt.Dispose();
        }

        public static void SetDatabaseLogon(this ReportDocument report, string username, string password, string odbcDataSource)
        {
            // first we need to switch all tables of all reports (main- and subreports) to the target odbcDataSource.
            foreach (Table table in report.Database.Tables)
            {
                table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = username;
                table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = password;
                table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = odbcDataSource;
                table.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = string.Empty;
            }

            if (!report.IsSubreport)
            {
                foreach (ReportDocument subreport in report.Subreports)
                {
                    subreport.SetDatabaseLogon(username, password, odbcDataSource);
                }

                // now that we've setup the report, we can perform the actual database logon
                report.SetDatabaseLogon(username, password, odbcDataSource, string.Empty, true);
                Console.WriteLine(username);
                Console.WriteLine(password);
                Console.WriteLine(odbcDataSource);
                Console.WriteLine("Set Datasource to test epicor");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }


        public static List<string> GetReports()
        {
            var FileList = new List<string>();
            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\cytepicortest\EpicorData\CustomReports");//Assuming Test is your Folder
            FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.rpt"); //Getting Text files
            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
               FileList.Add(file.Name);
            }
            return FileList;
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you meant changed DB or DB object name?

Comment: I am trying to replace the current database and tables with a new database (which is a copy) and replace current tables with new database tables for all reports. I have in the images exactly what I mean.

Comment: Are you sure this is necessary?  Most systems I've worked with had code built into the software that allows the reports to get database logon information from the software to ensure the report is running from the same database as the software, be it production or test.  As long as schemas match, I've only needed to change the database when developing an individual report.

Comment: No as you see when I update the database itself it still has the old database for the tables, makes no sense in my opinion.

Comment: Late feedback from [same question at sap.com](https://answers.sap.com/questions/12868634/c-changing-the-datasource-and-catalog-of-all-table.html): "use `ReplaceConnection()` to update the data source [...] and set log on info for each subreport".